# not able to get editable cells values into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets, jqgrid

using following code I can get values of grid but not able to get editable cell values -

```
              var rows= jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getRowData');
              var paras=new Array();
                for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
                {
                    var row=rows[i];
                    paras.push($.param(row));
                }
                 for(var i=0;i < paras.length;i++){
                var pa1=paras[i];
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "JQGridServlet?action=arraydata&"+pa1,
```

so please suggest me to ho to get editable cells values into array?

Comment: So you modified the question. :) Well, does the variable paras now contain the grid data? Can you post the value in paras after the above operation?

Comment: No its not go in side servlet.

Comment: Or alert the value of paras on submit click. And check the value..

Comment: now it go in side the servlet and also I can get uneditable cell values but still I am not able to get values of editable cells through an array.

Comment: Please update your question by including the code for jqgrid and the value that reaches the servlet

Comment: so I am update my question with code so please try to solve my problem

Comment: I asked you to post the code for jqgrid!. LIke this: 
            $( '#list' ).jqGrid( { ...});

Comment: Ans also include the servlet code